# Problems boot Ubuntu 13.04, kernel version 3.8.0 UEFI boot

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, boot

few days ago I UPGRADED my Ubuntu 12.10 to Ubuntu 13.04 version on my NP300E5C samsung notebook with ssd. I reloaded ubuntu few times and everything has gone well, BUT after a complete shutdown I restarted my notebook and, loading Kernel version 3.8.0, it hangs on black screen and Ubuntu cannot load. It works only selecting kernel version 3.5.0; I don't have a dual boot. I boot Ubuntu with UEFI boot-loader embedded in my samsung pc. Please help me, it is my working pc and is very important to have all things working fine for my job. Thanks for your time

Comment: if you have ur work backed up i would suggest a fresh install. I did an upgrade the other day on my laptop from 12.10 to 13.04 (the same as u) and it was not playing nice. So i did a fresh install and now everything is ok.

Comment: If you remove the `quiet` option from the kernel line, what output do you get? (you can edit the kernel options before booting on the grub selection screen)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem trivially. I started first time with kernel 3.5.0.x then I rebooted and then shutdown and magically it worked and works fine with 3.8.0.x kernel. I don't know why, I think that's some grub strange behavior, in fact I had the same problem with 12.10 version and I re-installed grub through boot-repair tool.